# fflush and while loop

Tags: c, linux, while-loop, fflush

I have been trying to use fflush to make a progress bar.
To test fflush, I wrote the small code below.

It works as it supposed to when I uncomment "sleep(1);" 
but it works in an unexpected way if 
it remains commented out. It prints the first dash, waits than prints all remaining 
9 of them and quits.

I don't understand why it makes a difference.

```
int main()
{
    int f,j;
    j =0;
    for(f=0;f<10;f++)
     {
        printf("-");
        fflush(stdout);
        while(j++<1000000000);
        //sleep(1);
     }
}
```

Comment: I hope you're not actually planning to use `while (j++ < 1000000000)` instead of a call to `sleep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your for loop like so:

from:

```
for(f=0;f<10;f++)
```

to:

```
for(f=0, j=0; f<10; f++, j=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `j` back to zero after the while loop. The next iteration it will just skip over the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't reset the inner loop counter `j` to zero at each outer loop iteration, i.e. the `while()` is executed only the first time around. Nothing to so with `fflush()` :)

Answer (score 1):

For the first 'for' iteration `f=0`, it will print the first dash, then will run `j` up to 1 billion, and then it will print the nine remaining dashes because j is greater than 1 billion hence no more wait or delay. That is how it should run if `sleep(1)` is commented out.

You may wish to add line `j=0;` after the while loop to reset j to zero.

When you uncomment `sleep(1)` there will be a small almost unnoticeable delay (I guess 1 millisecond) after printing each dash.